# User permission restriction

Tags: linux, centos5

I am using CentOS 5.5.

I would like to control user that can access granting application. User can't use any application or any resource (e.g calculator, default application of normal user)that isn't granted by root user.

User can't do anything that isn't granted by administrator.
For example
User can't use application that is installed by me because I don't grant this application for this user.

Comment: What u want to do with that user?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is application white-listing. You could accomplish this by getting your hands dirty with SELinux. Walking you through it is a tall order for this site unless you come with a very specific question about a problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that an application can be downloaded from the internet or another source and can be run without an installation procedure. For example you can download the firefox tarball from the Mozilla FTP and run directly from the homedir of the user, without any root privileges.

An X session for example runs many binaries (dcopserver, klauncher, etc...) all running with the user id. So will you allow all those processes separately ? I'm not sure that the approach of forbidding the access to an application is the best way to operate. Can you describe a bit more what you want to achieve ?

For example, calculator can easily be replaced by the python interpreter (I do it all the time). Does it mean you will also forbid the python interpreter ?